# How do I get this iTunes song on an Android device?

Tags: music, itunes

I want to buy [this song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7JgVqbh8nE), but it appears it's only offered on iTunes.  I have no idea if it's DRM protected or not, I just want it on my Moto X.

- What are the most direct and straigtforward steps to determine *if* I can put this song on my device, and how I can do it?

I would like to purchase the song directly from my phone, but I have both a PC and a Mac

Answer (score 1):

In recent years, Apple has sold songs on iTunes without DRM. You can [convert them to other formats](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1550) pretty easily, then just drop it onto your Moto X using a USB cable (Or even just email it to yourself, then download it using your email app on the phone).

Music stored on the phone should automatically be added to your "On Device" library in the Play Music app. I would recommend making sure you save it somewhere standard like `/sdcard/Music/` for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like iTunes much, but I keep it around because I still have an iPod floating about. I have the Google Play Music uploader synced to iTunes. So, were I to buy a DRM-free song in iTunes (and it, of course, is locally downloaded) it will automatically be converted (if necessary) and added to my Google Play Music library and I can pin it to my device for offline enjoyment.

The only time this doesn't work flawlessly is when the source song has DRM on it. If I recall, though, everything coming out of iTunes these days lacks DRM. (At least, music is that way.)